# Linker cannot find local shared library

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries

I'm trying a very simple exmaple to create a shared library and link to it.  The shared library is as follows:

```
#ifndef ARDUGRAB_H_
#define ARDUGRAB_H_

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace ArduGrabLibrary{

    class ArduGrab{
    public:
            ArduGrab();
            virtual void initCamera();
            virtual void setSim(bool sim);
            virtual void setDebug(bool debug);
    private:
            bool debug = false;
            bool sim = false;
    };
}
```

Then the source code file is just as simple:

```
#include "ardugrab.h"


namespace ArduGrabLibrary
{

    ArduGrab::ArduGrab(){
            std::cout << "IMX298 Constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    void ArduGrab::initCamera(){
            if (this->debug){
                    cout << "init camera" << std::endl;
            }
    }

    void ArduGrab::setSim(bool sim){
            this->sim = sim;
            if (this->debug){
                    cout << "set sim to " << std::boolalpha << this->sim << std::endl;
            }
    }

    void ArduGrab::setDebug(bool debug){
            this->debug = debug;
            if (this->debug){
                    cout << "set debug to " << std::boolalpha << this->sim << std::endl;
            }
    }
}
```

I'm then compiling that into a shared library with:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -o ardugrab.so ardugrab.cpp
```

All good, we get an ardgrab.so library so to test it, with the following code in teh same directory as the .so and .h files from above:

```
#include "ardugrab.h"

using namespace ArduGrabLibrary;

int main() {
    std::cout << "starting program" << std::endl;
    ArduGrab* ardu = new ArduGrab();
    ardu->setDebug(true);
    //imx298->setSim(true);
    //imx298->initCamera();
    return 0;
}
```

So now we need to compile this into an executable with:

```
g++ -L. -lardugrab -o testardugrab testardugrab.cpp
```

This however fails to find the ardugrab.so file, the follow error message appears:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ArduMipiGrab $ g++ -L. -lardugrab -o testardugrab testardugrab.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lardugrab
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to . export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. but still nothing.

As you can see I'm a bit new with compiling c++, can someone please advise me as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Reagrds,

Neil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is becuase you are using the `-l` flag.

When you use this flag (Rather than specify a library specifically) it assumes a certain naming convention.

```
-lX
```

The linker assumes the file name is

```
libX.so (or libX.a)
```

So the commands you want are:

```
> g++ -fPIC -shared -o libardugrab.so ardugrab.cpp
> #                    ^^^
> g++ -L. -lardugrab -o testardugrab testardugrab.cpp
```

Note: The environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used at runtime when the standard library tries to find and load required shared libraries. I.E. it is not used during compilation to find shared libraries to link with.